# KivyMD ,MDCard inside MDScrollView is showing hard shadow

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I am trying to make a Card scroll list inside navigation, but when it is changed one navigation item to another and came back to the previous navigation item, a dark shadow is showing when scrolling, I think the shadow is not scrolling when I change back to the tab

Here what it looks like

Before navigating

[image: Before]

After changing back

[image: After]

IDK what I am doing wrong

Here is my Excel.kv

```
MDBoxLayout:
orientation: 'vertical'

MDTopAppBar:
    title: 'Excel App'
    anchor_title: 'center'
    elevation: 2
    left_action_items: [['home', lambda x: x]]
    right_action_items:[['magnify', lambda x: x], ['menu', lambda x:x]]

MDBottomNavigation:
    panel_color: '#eeeaea'
    MDBottomNavigationItem:
        name: 'Home'
        text: 'Home'
        icon: 'home'
        MDBoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            MDScrollView:
                MDCard:
                    size_hint: 1, .2
                    pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
                    focus_behavior: True
                    md_bg_color: "#eeeeee"
                    unfocus_color: "#eeeeee"
                    focus_color: "#cccccc"
                    elevation: 2
                    ripple_behavior: True
                    MDBoxLayout:
                        orientation: 'vertical'
                        MDLabel:
                            halign: 'center'
                            bold: True
                            text: 'Name'
                        MDBoxLayout:
                            MDLabel:
                                text: 'Street'
                                halign: 'center'
                                theme_text_color: "Custom"
                                text_color: 'gray'

                            MDLabel:
                                text: 'Box Type'
                                halign: 'center'
                                theme_text_color: "Custom"
                                text_color: 'gray'

                            MDLabel:
                                text: 'Box No.'
                                halign: 'center'
                                theme_text_color: "Custom"
                                text_color: 'gray'

    MDBottomNavigationItem:
        name: 'Streets'
        text: 'Streets'
        icon: 'list-box'
        MDBoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            MDScrollView:
                MDCard:
                    size_hint: 1, .2
                    pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
                    focus_behavior: True
                    md_bg_color: "#eeeeee"
                    unfocus_color: "#eeeeee"
                    focus_color: "#cccccc"
                    elevation: 2
                    ripple_behavior: True
                    MDLabel:
                        text: 'Working'

    MDBottomNavigationItem:
        name: 'Customers'
        text: 'Customers'
        icon: 'account'
```

and here is my main.py

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp


class ExcelApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = 'Light'
        self.theme_cls.material_style = 'M3'
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = 'Blue'
        Builder.load_file('Excel.kv')

    def on_start(self):
        for i in recent:
            pass
```

I updated everything to latest version plz help

[image: Modules]